# How to custom mutilevel tab using Django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I want to use Django form to do something like this
[image]

When I choose **country** like China,**provience** will show the provience belong to China as well as **city**,all my data is stored in my json file.Everything runs perfect except when I trying to use Django form to custom my form,I can't find the field in **forms** to custom like that.

I also know I can cutsom a single choice using ChoiceField.

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    STATUS_CHOICES = #some choices
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES, label="", initial='', widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

Comment: You will need ajax calls. What have you tried?

Comment: Use ajax to call the json data? My class include many ##forms.Fiels##,which one should I use for that ?

Comment: You need to load 'provinces' according to the selected 'country'. So, when you select a country, you send an ajax call to a view, where you perform a query to get the provinces corresponding to the selected country, and returns them in a json format, with that json that contains provinces, you populate the 'province' combo.

Comment: Thanks Gocht,I need Django to know I use a mutilevel choice in this situation, so which kind of field should I choose like emailfield, charfield, choicefield to let Django know and display like that?

Comment: Django wont do this by magic, you need ajax calls